# Question about continuous functions and the difference between the values of the function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is it true that if a function $f$ is continuous at a point $p$ then for ever $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $$|x_1-p| < |x_2-p| < \delta \implies |f(x_1) - f(p)| < |f(x_2) - f(p)| < \epsilon?$$
That is, the closer the $x$s near $p$, then the closer the value of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking whether every function continuous at a point is monotone near that point. The answer is no, and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x\sin \frac1x, & \text{if } x\ne 0, \\
0, & \text{if } x =0
\end{cases}
$$
is a standard counterexample.
[image]